# Error installing heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

now,I want to install `heroku` to study rails deployment.

I execute the following code

```
sudo gem  install heroku
```

but I get the error

```
ERROR:  Error installing heroku:
    rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

then I execute the code:

```
ruby -v
```

I get the result

```
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
```

so it shows that my ruby version >= 1.9.2.

why I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the heroku gem directly into the RVM environment and gemset you want to use it in:

gem install heroku

If you do not have RVM this is a linux command to install the heroku Toolbelt!

wget -qO- toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

If you do not have a Ruby Version manager I would install one.

Comment: could you please tell me how I should " install the heroku gem directly into the RVM environmen",what command should I execute in terminal? I am a beginner,thank you very much!

Comment: Tell me more about your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Install `rvm`

1)then `rvm use 1.9.3` it will brings the ruby version 1.9.3

2)`gem install heroku`

Comment: do you have rvm > 1.9.3?